# Error: cannot find module "react-scripts/scripts/init.js' when tryping to install react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this issue when creating a new project, no idea what's really happening it's annoying. I tried to clean the cache, update the create-react-app, but still, the same thing happens. Thanks in advance!

Image of Issue, screenshot:

[image: Image of Issue, Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I am new at Node.js like you but try:

1. run `npm init`, in VS code terminal
2. `npm i react-scripts` (if you didn't install)